# Change to and from 4g using Tasker

Tags: settings, tasker

I downloaded Tasker for Android and I'm trying to do the following:

Condition1:

- On Chrome browser startup, go to "mobile network connections" and change from 3g to 4g.

Condition2:

- On Chrome browser exit, go to "mobile network connections" and change from 4g to 3g.

Can you write the steps down for me to do the above please?

Comment: Maybe you should consider Llama - it has almost all the features but it is way simpler to use.

Comment: I guess i read your question wrong

Comment: No worries :) 
But do you have the answer to my original question?

Comment: What phone are you using? What version of Android? Are you using a custom ROM? if so which one? The answer depends on these things

Comment: Galaxy note 2, international version, unrooted.

Comment: You could use [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/app-5-0-root-toggle-network-type-5-0-2g-3g-lte-xda-exclusive-free-version.2945406/) one here as Tasker plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Your GSM carrier might have different [APN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Point_Name)s for 3G and 4G service. If so, you might be able to find a way to use Tasker to automate the modification of your data APN between the two. I've looked, but all I can find is using Tasker + [APNDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codecarpet.apndroid.pro&hl=en) to append "apndroid" to the APN name to disable mobile data entirely. Useful in its own way, but not in your use-case. If anyone else can figure out a way to make it happen though, I think the potential is there.

Otherwise, I found a forum post describing [how to use Tasker to toggle 4G data](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codecarpet.apndroid.pro&hl=en). They list instructions for toggling LTE; I don't know if it will work for toggling HSDPA/HSPA+ 4G on your Note II but it might be worth a shot. Here are the juicy bits, modified slightly for clarity:

> You must be rooted and running a custom ROM that supports 4G toggling (i.e. [AOKP](http://aokp.co/)).
>
> - **Step 1:** Download [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin&hl=en)
> - **Step 2:** Open the app, go to Options and scroll down to Custom ROM Actions and ensure that "LTE" is checked
> - **Step 3:** Open up Tasker and create a profile entitled "4G On" and choose your first context (App = Chrome)
> - **Step 4:** Click New Task at the top of the tasks list and name it 4G On.
> - **Step 5:** Click the + button and scroll to Plugins and you will see Secure Settings. Click it.
> - **Step 6:** You will see edit configuration; click edit
> - **Step 7:** Now you will see a list of the options you have enabled in Secure Settings. We care about 4G, so scroll down to LTE and click it. Then it will ask you what state you want LTE to be in. This is the 4G On profile, so click On. Save and apply the task.
> - **Step 8:** Repeat steps 3-7, but now choose the context you want for 4G to be off, name your profile and task 4G Off, and when you get to the configuration settings in Secure Settings, make sure you check Off for the state of LTE. Save and apply the task.

Comment: Thanks for replying!  
I have a note 2, GSM version, International version.
It's not rooted so no custom ROM.
I presently use this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wmba.android.toggle4gforrazr (4g Toggle) to first click the icon, then change from 3g to 4g and vice versa, which is quite a pain in the behind.

Comment: @Ryan - Sorry, I've got no idea where I got "Atrix" from! Do you know if your carrier has different APNs for 3G and 4G service?

Comment: No idea, How do I find out? My carrier is "tele2" in Sweden (www.tele2.se)

Comment: I'm relying on Google Translate here, but [I think the answer is yes](http://www.tele2.se/kundservice/mobilt-bredband/apn.aspx). Are you using the "4g.tele2.se" APN? [Here's how to check](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-note-lte/596583-how-do-you-change-apn-settings-galaxy-note.html). If you can find a way to automate the modification of your APN settings with Tasker you might be in luck.

Comment: Ok, did some digging, the APN is 4g.tele2.se as you said, there is just one APN that I seem to be using. It (seems that) I dont need to change the APN but I need to change the "Network mode" from "GSM only" to "LTE/GSM/WCDMA (Auto mode)"